# Ajax post call cannot access 'this' inside .then

Tags: reactjs, ajax, state

I know the issue is that 'this' is technically outside of the scope of the function (this function is defined within a react class), but I've tried binding it a few different ways and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
const sendEmail = () => {
  this.openBackDrop();
  var data = {
    service_id: "redacted",
    template_id: "redacted",
    user_id: "redeacted",
    template_params: {
      from_name: this.state.name,
      message: this.state.message,
      rating: this.state.rating,
      requested: this.state.requestedProjects.toString(),
    },
  };
  $.ajax("url_goes_here", {
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
  })
    .done(function () {
      alert("Your mail is sent!");
      this.setState({
        requestedProjects: [],
        rating: "0",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        message: "",
        buttonDisabled: true,
        emailDisabled: true,
        backDrop: false,
      });
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
      alert("Oops... " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
};
```

Can anyone throw me a quick bone here? To be clear I want different things to happen to the state depending on whether or not the request succeeded, otherwise I would just do it in the main block of the function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `then` in your code, so I guess you mean `done`. Easiest way would be to use arrow expression, so instead of `function(){...}` do `() => {...}` this way the this is same as inside `sendEmail`. You can also create function and store it in cost, i.e. `const onDone = function(){...}` and then bind it to `this` so e.g. `.done(onDone.bind(this))`